# WordPress edit_user_profile_update update secondary role

Tags: users, user-roles

I am trying to save secondary role field in user-edit.php which is independent of WP's main roles. I had no problem with saving other custom fields that are unique but for roles (wp_capabilities), it looks like it first saves my roles (I set sleep(10) to check in database in the process) and at the end of request, WP saves main role field which overwrites my previously saved role.

Is there any way to order events somehow so my function executes at the very end of request?

Here's what I've got so far:

Hooks:

```
<?php
add_action( 'edit_user_profile',        array( $this, 'test_profile_form'));
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', array( $this, 'test_save_profile_form' ));
```

Callbacks:

```
function hook_save_profile_form($user_id) {
        if(!current_user_can("edit_user",$user_id)) {
            return false;
        }
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
        $user->add_role($_POST['secondary-role']);
        //debug
        sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: It has been awhile since I seriously looked into it, but I am pretty sure you can't assign a "secondary" role. One user; one role. One role will overwrite the other.

Comment: It is indeed possible because there is add_role and set_role (set_role removes all current and sets the one provided). I used bbPress as an example, where wp_capabilities for each user look something like `a:2:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;s:13:"bbp_keymaster";b:1;}`

Comment: WP core can be configured to handle multiple roles for each user.  Unfortunately the profile cannot handle that situation.  I am not sure if it is possible to enable multiple roles in the profile via plugins - for display yes, for updating = don't know.

Comment: Interesting... you are right. +1 to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found solution and the right hook for this: `profile_update` is called at the end of `wp_insert_user` in `user.php` which is called from `edit_user`.

wp_insert_user ending:

```
if ( $update )
        do_action('profile_update', $user_id, $old_user_data);
    else
        do_action('user_register', $user_id);

    return $user_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using the `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` hooks, but the database information was being overwritten.  Those hooks work when editing the current user, but when an administrator edits another user's profile, the information is not persisted.  I switched to using the `profile_update` hook and the updates were persisted when editing any user, so this appears to be the best hook to use in cases where you want to edit all user profiles and not just the current user.

Comment: just want to confirm that using `profile_update` solved the same problem i was having... data was not persisting until i used `profile_update` instead of `edit_user_profile_update`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third argument of `add_action` to set the filter priority. The functions default value is 10, so something >10 should work.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: I've tried that already but that can't help because user-edit.php calls `edit_user($user_id)` right below `edit_user_profile_update` hook...

Comment: Did you try another hook? `profile_update` located in `wp-includes/user.php` is called right after user data has been saved. I think this where you should put all update operations.

Answer (score 0):

Using `profile_update` hook I can solve this problem.

Comment: Please add a sufficient explanation **how** it would solve the problem - thanks.