# Adding an additional role to an Administrator

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

User 19 is a WP Admin.

```
$user = new WP_user( 19 );
$user->add_role( 'custom_role' );
```

The above code works and adds the `custom_role` role.

However, when I run the same code on the `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` hook it does not.

I have added a checkbox to the user profile page. The function called from both the above hooks then...

```
if( user_can( $user_id, 'administrator' ) ) {
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );      
    if( ! empty( $_POST['my_checkbox'] ) )  {

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_checkbox', true );
        $user->add_cap( 'one_cap' );
        $user->add_cap( 'two_cap' );
        $user->add_role( 'custom_role' );

    }
}
```

`one_cap` and `two_cap` are both set correctly for the user, but no sign of `custom_role` and nothing written to the debug log.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the profile_update hook and in the hooked function, run this check to make sure that it's adding the previous data to the users profile on update too.

```
if ( $update ){
        do_action('profile_update', $user_id, $old_user_data);
}else{
        do_action('user_register', $user_id);
}
return $user_id;
```

This answer can help you understand it more: [WordPress edit_user_profile_update update secondary role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131488/wordpress-edit-user-profile-update-update-secondary-role)

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense that I was hooking too early

Comment: you're welcome! voting up the answer helps me too! ;)